# What is the difference between hibernate lock mode UPGRADE_NOWAIT and UPGRADE?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the difference between hibernate (v3.6) lock mode UPGRADE_NOWAIT and UPGRADE?

In what cases do we use each of these lock modes?

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference lies in lock acquisition (wait or nowait)

`UPGRADE` is deprecated. Attempt to obtain an upgrade lock, using an Oracle-style `select for update`.

`UPGRADE_NOWAIT` - Attempt to obtain an upgrade lock, using an Oracle-style `select for update **nowait**`. The semantics of this lock mode, `once obtained, are the same as UPGRADE`.

Comment: It would be much better if could explain the basics because I don't know the term 'Oracle-style'. Also, what does 'nowait' signify here.

Also, why even the upgrade lock is used? Why is it deprecated?

Also, you didn't answer "In what cases do we use each of these lock modes?". It seems that you just copy pasted the answer from the hibernate docs which does not explain anything.